# How to get information from two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I stuck with mysql here,
I need to get information from couple of tables based on the city as follows:

```
table1: users contains id, name, city.
table2: users_products contains id, user_id, type.
```

I want to retrieve id, city, name, product_id, product_type based on the city.
Please help me.

Comment: like a JOIN between the tables?

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.id, t1.city, t1.name, t2.product_id from users t1, products t2
where city = "City Name";
```

Comment: In your query, how is `t1` and `t2` related?  You don't have a join or a where clause linking them.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.*, up.id AS ProductID, up.type
FROM users_products AS up 
JOIN users AS u
ON u.id = up.user_id
WHERE u.city = "City"
```

Comment: You have two tables that you are trying to link to each other.  In order to link the tables you have to find the field that matches them together.  That field happens to be `id` in the `users` table and `user_id` in the `users_products` table.  To find out more information about JOINS see [**SQL Joins**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).  In the query you see `AS u` that is an alias for users.  Then anywhere in the query where you see `u.`, you know I am referring to the `users` table.  Does that help any?  Also, if my answer was the best fit for you, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks mate for reminding me w3schools.com as a suggested link, understood clearly now.